# Thingsboard Integration does not bring data to root rule chain

Tags: thingsboard

I succesfully create uplink and downlink converters and integration. I can see the incoming messages in the debug page of integration yet there is nothing going on in the root rule chain. I cannot see any valid reason for that.

I have been trying to read the 'thingsboard.log' file, but there have been no updates or new entries in the file for the past three hours. As a result, I am unable to view the most recent logs in that file.

I can try IoT gateway instead of integration but I want to understand what is going under the hood.

Edit: In /usr/local/kafka/logs path and in controller.log.2023-05-31-05 file :

[image]

Edit- In the thingsboard.log file there are error indicating *null pointer exception* and *reason must be empty*
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by deleting the existing tenant and creating a new one. Additionally, I discovered that even if I used the default tenant profile for a new tenant, the problem persisted. To address this, I created a new tenant profile specifically for new tenants. By implementing this solution, the problem was effectively resolved.